# How to install latest version of Python and python packages in CentOS without internet connection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, package, centos7

I am using a computer with the high processing power. This computer is installed with CentOS and I want to install Python 3.6 along with Python packages. The problem I face is that I am not allowed to have an internet connection so I cannot download anything. What should I do?

Comment: If you can pre-download the related `.whl` files for the packages (which you might find on pypi.org), you can save them on some removable media and `pip install -U *.whl` (or whatever specific `.whl`) with the environment activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do, but it is only in relation to my experience in clusters:

- I'd use Environment-Modules & EasyBuild
- Go to another machine on which you have access and go under the same $HOME dir
- First you install EasyBuild under your $HOME(/.local) via the bootstrap process
- Then you identify a bare Python/3.6 of EasyBuild and install that - as a test
- At this point you should check you can make a tarball from $HOME/.local/EasyBuild
- Take said tarball and install at new system and see if things works as they should
- Keep expanding the list of Python packages the EasyBuild way, until not hungry

Once there, this can be expanded indefinitely.

- Drawback: too many moving parts.
- Advantage: process & parts get **frozen**, this will be fully reproducible in the eternity.

Answer (score 2):

**TO UPGRADE PYTHON**

You are able to upgrade your python without internet conection using the binaries that you can find in Python site. [Here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/) is the link for the 3.7.0 version.

**TO INSTALL NEW PACKAGES**

First, you will need a computer with internet connection. Then download the desired package:

```
pip3 download numpy
```

Then compress the package files and using a pendrive or something else, send to the computer withou internet connection. Finally, decrompress your package and install the using the .whl file and the following command:

```
pip3 install path_to_whl_file.whl -f --no-index ./
```

**INSTALL PIP**

If you need to install the pip in the computer withou connection, you need do an approach similar. Download the get-pip.py file using:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

And put the file in the non-connection computer and install using:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Download anaconda. Transfer the single file to your machine with usb, cdrom, ssh, or any method. Then run it with or without root (or admin account). Both way works.

https://www.anaconda.com/download

The kernel of linux has to be new enough.

If you need more package, download source from pypi, transfer, and install manually (`python setup.py install`) If it complains about dependencies, download the dependencies and do the same.

Answer (score -1):

Put together a list of the packages you want and ask the machine's admin to install them.

If you're not allowed an internet connection you're also not allowed to sneakernet new code in.

PS. If this is for work or school, circumventing security policies is a good way to get fired or expelled.